# Methods for solving recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

The problem I have is to solve the following recurrence relation :

$S(1) = 1$

$S(n) =  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (i\cdot S(i))$

I figured out the solution is:

$S(n) = \frac{n!}{2}$

mostly by calculating the first few values for $n$ and trying to find patterns.

However, I would like to know if there is a more structured method(s) for finding the solution?

Thank you :)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think you meant your formula to hold only for $n>1$, as $S(1)=1\neq \frac {1!}2$.

Comment: To your question, note that, for large enough $n$, $S(n)=S(n-1)+(n-1)S(n-1)=nS(n-1)$ which makes it clear you are dealing with a factorial.

Comment: I think  guessing and proving is the simplest way for this. You only need to prove what you have guessed, which can be done through mathematical induction. All you might need to prove is the following: 

$$1(1!)+2(2!)+\dots+(n-1)(n-1)! = n!$$